# Including metadata in GeoPackage file written using GeoPandas/Fiona

Tags: python, geopandas, metadata, geopackage, fiona

I have a Geopandas GeoDataFrame with a couple of categorical columns that I want to write to a GeoPackage file. GeoPandas/Fiona/GeoPackage [does not support categorical columns directly](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1883), so I'm changing those columns to their int codes before writing the GeoPackage and making a dict mapping code to category. So far so good.

Now, on reading in the GeoPackage file, I need to know *which* columns were categorical, and, ideally, get back the code--category mappings. And I'm stumbling trying to find a way to include that metadata with a GeoPackage file, at least as written from GeoPandas or Fiona. I see the [GeoPackage standard](https://docs.ogc.org/is/12-128r17/12-128r17.html) provides for metadata, but I can't find any way to include it using Fiona or GeoPandas that survives writing the file and reading it back in.

Answer (score 4):

The metadata tables in the GeoPackage are made for the metadata according to ISO: 19115-1:2014 Geographic information — Metadata — Part 1: Fundamentals (2014). It is also possible to register other metadata domains, including your application specific ones, into gpkg_metadata_reference but that feel all too complicated for your needs. I would rather have a look at the GeoPackage Schema extension http://www.geopackage.org/guidance/extensions/schema.html.

Probably you could utilize a Data Column Constraint of type "enum".

> Data Column Constraints
>
> The lowercase gpkg_data_column_constraints constraint_type column
> value specifies the type of constraint: "range", "enum", or "glob"
> (GLOB is a text pattern match - see [33]). The case sensitive value
> column contains an enumerated legal value for constraint_type "enum",
> a pattern match string for constraint_type "glob", or NULL for
> constraint_type "range". The set of value column values in rows of
> constraint_type "enum" with the same constraint_name contains all
> possible enumerated values for the constraint name.

With the enum constraint you could define and query which columns are categorized and which values are valid in each column. The code -- category mapping is supported directly because the table has place for code values and descriptions.

```sql
CREATE TABLE gpkg_data_column_constraints (
constraint_name TEXT NOT NULL,
constraint_type TEXT NOT NULL, // 'range' | 'enum' | 'glob'
value TEXT,
min NUMERIC,
min_is_inclusive BOOLEAN, // 0 = false, 1 = true
max NUMERIC,
max_is_inclusive BOOLEAN, // 0 = false, 1 = true
description TEXT,
CONSTRAINT gdcc_ntv UNIQUE (constraint_name, constraint_type, value)
)
```

This mail https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2021-April/053827.html suggests that it was not implemented but the corresponding pull request https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/3638 does have code for the GeoPackage driver and even on ogrinfo example about how the enumerated values appear in the ogrinfo report. In a comments you can also read discussion about how to access the field domains from fiona.